# Ada ambiguous expression with Get

Tags: generics, ada, io-redirection

I am trying to use IOredirection to create, add to, delete from and print two arrays, one of integers and one of floats using generics.

Things are fine for the integer array, but when at "get(fVal)" I am getting the error "ambiguous expression (cannot resolve "Get").

I thought it might have something to do with the float array being after the integer array. I put it before the integer array but still got the same error for the float array.

I am still new to Ada so I am struggling to grasp it sometimes.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with CreateList;

procedure Main is

   package IntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer); use IntIO;
   package FloatIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(Float); use FloatIO;

begin

   declare
      max: integer;   --declaring integer named "max"
      val: integer;
      del: integer;
      pointer : integer := 0;
      len : integer := 0;
      procedure MyPut(x: integer) is begin
            IntIO.Put(x, 0, 10);
      end MyPut;

      package C_List is new CreateList(max, integer, MyPut); use C_List;

   begin
      get(max);                              --assigns input for array size and assigns value to "max"
      for row in 1 .. max loop
         get(val);
         C_List.add_to_list(val);            --calls procedure to add value 12 to array
      end loop;
      C_List.print_list;                     --calls procedure to print entire array
      len := C_List.length_of_list;          --calls function to determine the current length of array and assign the value to "len"
      for pointer in 1 .. len loop           --calls procedure to print individual value in array. Loops to print all values in array
         C_List.print_list(pointer);
      end loop;
      Put_Line("");
      get(del);
      C_List.delete_from_list(del);          --calls procedure to delete a value from array
      C_List.print_list;                     --calls procedure to print entire array
   end;

   

   declare
      max: integer;   --declaring integer named "max"
      fVal: float;
      del: integer;
      pointer : integer := 0;
      len : integer := 0;
      
      procedure MyPut(x: Float) is begin
         FloatIO.Put(x, 0, 0, 0);
      end MyPut;


      package B_List is new CreateList(max, float, MyPut); use B_List;

      begin
         get(max);                           --assigns input for array size and assigns value to "max"
      for row in 1 .. max loop
         get(fVal);
         B_List.add_to_list(fVal);           --calls procedure to add value 12 to array
      end loop;
         B_List.print_list;                  --calls procedure to print entire array
         len := B_List.length_of_list;       --calls function to determine the current length of array and assign the value to "len"
         for pointer in 1 .. len loop        --calls procedure to print individual value in array. Loops to print all values in array
            B_List.print_list(pointer);
         end loop;
         Put_Line("");
         get(del);
         B_List.delete_from_list(del);       --calls procedure to delete a value from array
         B_List.print_list;                  --calls procedure to print entire array
      end;

end Main;
```

createlist.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

package body CreateList is
   len: Integer;                       --declaring integer named "len"
   list: array(1..max) of itemType;    --making an integer array named "list"
   pnt: integer;                       --declaring integer named "pnt"

   procedure add_to_list (ListItem: in itemType) is begin   --procedure that adds new integer value to array "list"
      if pnt >= max then                                    --detects when array is full and can't fit more values
         Put_Line("**Detected Overflow**");
      else
         pnt := pnt + 1;                                    --moves pointer
         list(pnt) := ListItem;                             --adds new integer value to pointer index
      end if;
   end add_to_list;

   procedure delete_from_list (indx: in Integer) is begin   --procedure that removes an integer value from array "list"
      if indx = 0 then                                      --detects when array is empty and doesn't have any values to delete
         Put_Line("**Detected Underflow**");
      else
         for j in indx .. (pnt - 1) loop                    --loop to pop the stack after an integer has been removed from array
            if j < len then
               list(j) := list(j + 1);
            end if;
         end loop;

         pnt := pnt - 1;
      end if;
   end delete_from_list;

   function length_of_list return Integer is begin   --function to determine the current number of integers in array
      for i in 1 .. pnt loop
         len := len + 1;
      end loop;
      return len;
   end length_of_list;

   procedure print_list (indx: in Integer) is begin   --procedure that prints the integer at a given index of the array
      Put(list(indx));
      Put(" ");
   end print_list;

   procedure print_list is begin   --procedure that prints the entire array
      for i in 1 .. pnt loop
         Put(list(i));
         Put(" ");
      end loop;
      Put_Line("");
   end print_list;

begin
   pnt := 0;
   len := 0;

end CreateList;
```

createlist.ads

```
generic
   max: integer;
   type itemType is private;
   
   with procedure Put(x: itemType);

package CreateList is
      
   procedure add_to_list (listItem: in itemType);
   --   
   procedure delete_from_list (indx: in Integer);
   --   
   function length_of_list return Integer;
   --
   procedure print_list (indx: in Integer);
   procedure print_list;

end CreateList;
```

**Thank you @thindil.
I changed get(fVal) to FloatIO.get(fVal) and it worked.**

Comment: Note that source file names are immaterial in Ada. Ada doesn't care if the spec of your generic pkg Createlist is in createlist.ads or in CL.spc, or not in a file at all. Neither do we. (Note that some compilers are more picky, so when/if you ask about a specific compiler, the file names may be important.)

Comment: `ambiguous expression (cannot resolve "Get").` This is usually followed by a list of plausible resolutions it has found. Looking at this list will usually make it clear why it can't resolve to the one you intended. I believe Frederic has nailed the specific problem but more generally, Gnat compile error messages tend to go out of their way to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the compiler found a few references to the selected subprogram (in your case `get`) and can't decide which one should use because they all are look valid. In that situation you have to exactly tell the compiler which one you want to use by adding the proper package name. In your case it will be:

`get(max);` should be replaced by `IntIO.get(max);`

`get(val);` should be replaced by `IntIO.get(val);`

`get(fVal);` should be replaced by `FloatIO.get(fVal);`

That's probably all :)

Comment: There seems to be no trouble resolving the integer Gets. Sometimes fully resolved names are necessary, sometimes they add clarity for the reader, sometimes they are just clutter.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, for me it was a problem, GNAT doesn't want to compile the example code until I didn't clarified it. Thus probably it depends also on a compiler version.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you get this message is that you have two packages that provide a *put* for *Float*:

- Your instantiation of *Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Float)* named *FloatIO*
- The standard package for float named *Ada.Float_Text_IO*

Depending on your needs, you can use both and prefix or use only *Ada.Float_Text_IO* as you don't have a specific float type.

These was not that easy to see in the error message :

```
main.adb:23:40: warning: "max" may be referenced before it has a value
main.adb:61:10: ambiguous expression (cannot resolve "Get")
main.adb:61:10: possible interpretation at a-tiflio.ads:57, instance at line 9
main.adb:61:10: possible interpretation at a-tiflio.ads:57, instance at a-flteio.ads:20
gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error
```

The only clue is the last line telling that the interpretation comes from the instance at line 20 in *a-flteio.ads* which is the filename for *Ada.Float_Text_IO*.

As a note, even though *Ada.Float_Text_IO* is an instantiation looking like yours (i.e. *new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Float)*), it's not the same package from the compiler point of view.